# Como mostrar todos os números de um laço de repetição de um só vez no C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou vendo laço de repetição no C#, porém **eu preciso sempre apertar Space Bar para exibir cada número do laço, por exemplo de digito o número 100 e preciso apertar 100 vezes o Space Bar para mostrar um número crescente até o 100** e isso é cansativo, alguém sabe como mostrar todos os números de um laço de repetição no C# de uma só vez?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TesteLaco
{
    class Program3
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero, i = 1;
            Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"O número é: {i}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olhe para o código e siga a sua execução. Facilmente perceberá qual a linha que faz com que necessite de clicar numa tecla para ele prosseguir.

Comment: Conforme resposta dada em pergunta anterior, seu código continua problemático e se não começar mudar vai ter problemas pro resto da vida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas mude o Console.ReadKey(); para fora do for, em baixo dele.
Assim ele vai imprimir todos os números e depois vai esperar a key.

```
        for (i = 1; i <= numero; i++){

            Console.WriteLine($"O número é: {i}");

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.